# Asp Net Core How to render razor components using ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-components

In my razor page i can render a view component using ajax pretty easily. However razor components are much easier to work with since you can have everything in one file and less confusing when working with a self contained component. How can i do this for a razor component? Also my project is just razor pages and MVC controllers and currently using one razor component as a sidebar

```
public ViewComponentResult OnGetUserAsync(int id)
{
    FormInput = new FormModel(id);
    return ViewComponent("EditUser", FormInput);
}
```

Comment: If you are following the Blazor model for building your components, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1) should help you out. This will walk you through using JS Interop to get your data from an API, process it, and get it rendered.

Comment: @NikP not really into Blazor until WebAssembly is production ready, but i do like how razor components work and I'm using them on my razorpages/mvc project.